# Google Chrome v27 Extensions - Breaking Changes?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

does anyone know if Chrome has breaking changes in the extension handling in version 27? I don't mean the disabled manifest version 1.

I have the problem that the simulation of a unsafeWindow (access to the real website DOM) doesn't work anymore, prior to v27 this worked without a problem, but since v27 i only get the "safe" DOM, as in the sandboxed window object.

I have enabled manifest version 2 a long time ago, that not seems to be the problem.

My simple example Minifest (only necessary parts):

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    ...
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["xxx*", "xxx*", "xxx*"],
            "js": [
                "init.js"
            ],
            "run_at" : "document_start"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Example init.js:
Since v27 the script not reach the case console.log("work") because unsafeWindow doesn't have a jQuery instance in it (the real dom from the website has it), before v27 this always work.

```
// emulate unsafe window as in firefox
window.unsafeWindow || (
    unsafeWindow = (function() {
        var el = document.createElement('p');
        el.setAttribute('onclick', 'return window;');
        return el.onclick();
    }())
);
var ivb = setInterval(function(){
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.$ == "undefined" || !unsafeWindow.$("body").size()) return false;
    clearInterval(ivb);
    console.log("work");
}, 20);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should never have used the `unsafeWindow` hack. Just include jQuery with your extension to fix the problem.

Comment: I know but my extension doesn't work with the sandboxed window. I need access to all functions and script from the real DOM from the website. jQuery was just a example to show what's the problem is (no access to real DOM anymore, why?)

Comment: Inject a helper script which uses postMessage or custom events to invoke the functions in the page's context.

Comment: Ok, with a combination of `window.addEventListener("message", ...)`, native script injection (`document.appendChild`) and `window.postMessage(...)` i got it to work fine again. But i still don't know why this behaviour has changed. I cannot find some information in the changelog of chrome.

Comment: FYI, [Issue 222652: unsafeWindow workaround for extensions does not work in latest Chrome canary, but works in dev-m](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=222652)